# Getting values from Future instances

Tags: dart, dart-async

My data is something like this:

```
{
  "five": {
    "group": {
      "one": {
        "order": 2
      },
      "six": {
        "order": 1
      }
    },
    "name": "Filbert",
    "skill": "databases"
  },
  "four": {
    "group": {
      "three": {
        "order": 2
      },
      "two": {
        "order": 1
      }
    },
    "name": "Robert",
    "skill": "big data"
  },
  "one": {
    "name": "Bert",
    "skill": "data analysis"
  },
  "seven": {
    "name": "Colbert",
    "skill": "data fudging"
  },
  "six": {
    "name": "Ebert",
    "skill": "data loss"
  },
  "three": {
    "name": "Gilbert",
    "skill": "small data"
  },
  "two": {
    "name": "Albert",
    "skill": "non data"
  }
}
```

I am using the following function:

```
  Future retrieve(String id) async {
    Map employeeMap = await employeeById(id); //#1
    if (employeeMap.containsKey("group")) { //#2
      Map groupMap = employeeMap["group"];
      Map groupMapWithDetails = groupMembersWithDetails(groupMap); #3
      // above returns a Mamp with keys as expected but values 
      // are Future instances.
      // To extract values, the following function is
      // used with forEach on the map
      futureToVal(key, value) async { // #4
        groupMapWithDetails[key] = await value; 
      }
      groupMapWithDetails.forEach(futureToVal); // #4
    }
    return groupMapWithDetails;
   }
```

1. I access an employee (as a`Map`) from the database (Firebase)
2. If the employee is a leader (has a key "group")
3. I get the details of each of the employee in the group filled up from the database by calling a separate function.
4. Since the function returns a map with values that are instances of `Future`, I want to extract the actual values from them. For this a `forEach` is called on the map.
   However, I only get instances of Future as values.

How can I get the actual values?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no way to get back from async execution to sync execution.

To get a value from a `Future` there are two ways

pass a callback to `then(...)`

```
theFuture.then((val) {
  print(val);
});
```

or use `async`/`await` for nicer syntax

```
Future foo() async {
  var val = await theFuture;
  print(val);
}
```

Comment: Is there really NO WAY to access the value of Dart Future<Type> ? Something similar to SCALA's `Await.result(someFuture, 5.seconds)` ???

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki I don't understand your question. You can use `await` as shown above. There is no way to get the value synchronically though because otherwise it wouldn't have been made async in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to convert Future to a synchronous call. As in the previous example from SCALA - the call waits for a Future's value for 5 sec and fails if it cannot get future value. I.e. `var synchedVal  = Await.result(someFuture, 5.seconds)` and then `synchedVal` CAN be returned from a non-async function - as a Type and NOT as Future<Type>. In the await example you'd given the value CAN be used ONLY in the scope of the async function.

Comment: There is no such thing in Dart. What Scala does looks like an ugly hack. That might work if you have threads, but Dart does not have threads and Dart was also built to be compilable to JS and in JS there is no way to implement such a "hack".

Comment: I never use printing. What about actually returning the value?

Comment: @samuelnihoul see the first line of my answer. If you return the value, it's still wrapped in a Future. Future is just a wrapper over a callback. If you call a callback and pass a value, you also can't access the value from the code that passed the callback reference. When the callback is called, the execution of the code that passed the callback has long been completed already.

Comment: But there's the await keyword :-(

Comment: @samuelnihoul it's just simplified syntax. You can't do anything using `await` that you can't do without `await`. it's just `var result = await someAsync();` instead of `someAsync().then((result) { ... });`

Answer (score 4):

You are not waiting for the `await value` expressions to complete.

The `forEach` call runs through the map entries and starts an asynchronous computation for each. The future of that computation is then dropped because `forEach` doesn't use the return value of its function.
Then you return the map, far before any of the asynchronous computations have completed, so the values in the map are still futures. They will eventually change to non-futures, but you won't know when it's done.

Instead of the `forEach` call, try:

```dart
await Future.wait(groupMapWithDetails.keys.map((key) async {
  groupMapWithDetails[key] = await groupMapWithDetails[key];
});
```

This performs an asynchronous operation for each key in the map, and the waits for them all to complete. After that, the map should have non-future values.