# How convert FirebaseUser to string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Here is my code of a stateful class:

```
String id = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().toString();
```

my function :

```
readLocal() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
  if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
    groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
  } else {
    groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

It works fine in `String id`.

I want the ID to be the same as the current user UID.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` return a [`FirebaseUser`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser-class.html), which is an object with *all* user data. If you only want the [UID of the user](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserInfo/uid.html):

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String uid = user.uid;
```

---

**Update**: I just ran this and it prints the UID for me:

```
void _getUser() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  print(user.uid);
}
```

Which printed:

> flutter: P07IXLCrwEahYlDhzO1Iv0SKDat2

Things to notice:

- In order to be able to use `await` in the code, the method must be marked as `async`.

Comment: Error is : The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'Future<FirebaseUser>'.dart(undefined_getter)

Comment: Got it. `currentUser` is asynchronous, so you'll need to await the result. I updated my answer.

Comment: Again error : A value of type 'Future<FirebaseUser>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.dart(invalid_assignment)

Comment: Are you sure you added the `await` keyword? That should unwrap the `Future<FirebaseUser>` into `FirebaseUser`.

Comment: Yes, here is my code FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String uid = user.uid;

Comment: Hmmm.... as far as I know that should unwrap the `Future`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579358/getting-values-from-future-instances